# Google People API, return last modified date?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

Is there a way to retrieve the last modified timestamp for this endpoint GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}/connections

I am unable to see anything close to resembling this in the Person object fields described here https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person

Answer (score 2):

Recently an `updateTime` was added to the Source field https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Source.

You can get it by iterating over the `person.metadata.sources`